# How to make npm module(package) of Custom Module(android java) in react native and publish them?

Tags: android, react-native

How to make npm module(package) of Custom Module(android java) in react native and publish them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still interested in the answer, but as far as I can see, to create NPM module you simply need to call

```
npm init
```

and proceed with little quiz about your package details
OR call

```
npm init -y
```

to create module based on package content(if you already have some "index.js" to make "entry point" of your package).
Then you need to add all files that should not be published to ".gitignore" file to prevent publishing local files to production.
Final step is to call inside package folder:

```
npm publish
```

More information about package create process:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

More information about publish process:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

It is more complicated thing to create Native Module, but as far as you did not asked for this I just leave here a link to my blog post, which explains step-by-step how to create native module and hw to solve typical problems during this topic exploration: http://andengineer.blogspot.com/2016/12/react-native-bridged-android-components.html